# Unable to uploading addon into JIRA through local file system

Tags: jenkins, jira, add-on

I want to integrate Jenkins with JIRA. Unable to found Jenkins JIRA plugin through search results, so downloaded jira-jenkins-plugin-1.4.8.obr file into local system and tried to upload into JIRA using "Upload addon". When I tried, its showing only "URL text box" but not "From my computer" text box. Picture is as follows: Can any one help out with this stuff please. Thank you!! [image]

Comment: Are you using JIRA Cloud?

Comment: @scott Yes we are using JIRA cloud

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JIRA Cloud, you can only use [Atlassian Connect](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=315326753) add-ons, which are run themselves as cloud services. You cannot use any of the "Plugins 2"-style plugins which are uploaded as a .JAR or .OBR.

Your options are to:

- find an Atlassian Connect add-on that does what you want (you can filter the add-on list on the Atlassian Marketplace site for Cloud-compatible add-ons),
- download and host JIRA Server yourself, or
- migrate to a third-party JIRA hosting service (like [Seibert Media's Swift](https://swift.seibert-media.net)) that lets you install any of your own add-ons without restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try option1 earlier, but I was unable to find jenkins jira plugin in search results. Need to give a thought about other options.